Magisk stable to canary and vice-versa
Switching from Magisk stable (27.x) to canary (and vice-versa if I don't like canary) should be an easy thing but I don't see updated instructions.
I had done this way back, IIRC, by choosing custom update and inserting a link which doesn't work anymore
I have downloaded the canary version from the official Magisk site and what are the next steps? Please note that I don't want to unroot, root with canary and set up all the modules, which is a huge pain.
I can think of two options:

Install the canary apk and it gets installed over the stable with modules intact

Change the canary apk extension to zip and flash from within Magisk


I am not sure which is the best way, possibly their are better ways but my primary concern is not to set up modules again and easily reverse from canary to stable
All this for a banking app detecting root

Guess I was over thinking. It turned out to be simple:
To update to canary

Install the downloaded Canary app
Magisk app gets updated to canary
Update Magisk (su) by direct install (of course patched boot image needs to be in downloads folder)
Set the update channel to Canary

To revert to stable (not fully tested)

Set the update channel to stable and the app gets reverted to stable version
Do direct install for Magisk (su) — this part I didn't test being in a hurry.

Please feel free to edit the content or write up an answer
